# CSS: Centering this element

Tags: css

I tried for like an hour now getting it centered really fustrating I dont know how I should get it centered:

http://jsfiddle.net/KDUtP/

Notice that this is to a scrollable jquery plugin (just so you know, so dont complain for the maybe unnecessary css)

Comment: Which element exactly is supposed to be centered? :S

Comment: And what element(s) are you trying to center specifically? (Either way, It think setting the left/right margins (to a value like 0, auto, etc.) will fix the issue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is your container `display: inline-block`?

If you don't care about this, you can use `margin: 0 auto` to accomplish the centering.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're trying to do exactly but how is this?

http://jsfiddle.net/KDUtP/4/

Answer (score 0):

Give the container div a display: block; and add margin: 0 auto; to it.

```
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
```